# Can regularisation reduce the accuracy in the validation test?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, regularization, ridge-regression

I am constructing a CNN neural network with TensorFlow. I have run two versions of the CNN, one of them without regularization and the other with a kernel regularizer $L^2$ in each convolutional layer. The regularizer causes that the test accuracy and the validation accuracy are the same, nevertheless, it does not improves the validation accuracy. In fact, it is slightly reduced. Under what conditions does the regularizer not improve the accuracy?.